# Probabilistic interpretation linear regression implication step

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am reading Andrew Ng's notes on linear regression, and in this section, he attempts to derive the formula for the least squares using a probability approach: http://cs229.stanford.edu/summer2020/cs229-notes1.pdf

We assume: $$y^{(i)}=\theta ^{T}x^{(i)}+e^{(i)}$$

where where $\epsilon$ is distributed according to the normal distrubtion:  $N(0, \sigma^2)$

Thus, we can find the probability of $e^{(i)}$ as $$p(e^{(i)})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2π}σ}exp(-\frac{(e^{(i)})^2}{2σ^2})$$

However, in the next step, he says that **this implies** $$p(y^{(i)}|x^{(i)}; \theta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2π}σ}exp(-\frac{(y^{(i)} - \theta^Tx^{(i)})^2}{2σ^2})$$

and I am not sure how.

We see that $e$ is a RV and is distributed according the normal, so then how can we calculate the probability on something that isn't $e$?

Answer (score 1):

If $\theta$ and $x^{(i)}$ are fixed, then you are adding a constant to the normal distribution of $e^{(i)}$. This addition changes the center of the distribution but not the scale, so $y^{(i)}$ follows the distribution of $e^{(i)}$ but centered at $\theta^\top x^{(i)}$. In probability notation, this is $$y^{(i)}|x^{(i)},\theta \sim \mathcal{N}(\theta^\top x^{(i)}, \sigma^2).$$

Comment: Ok, so I understand that adding a constant ($\theta^Tx^{(i)}$) to a $0$ mean normal RV $e$, will shift the distributions mean to $\theta^Tx^{(i)}$. So in the notation above, does it mean that $y^{(i)}$ is a random variable?

Comment: Yes, $y^{(i)}$ is a random variable. When you fix $x^{(i)}$ and $\theta$, the variability of $y^{(i)}$ comes exclusively from the error term $e^{(i)}$.